# How can I create a time range with minutes?

Tags: c#, timespan

I have this function that returns a range of times (between two TimeSpan ) by incrementing an hour.

```
 public static IEnumerable < TimeSpan > Range(TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end) {
     for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0))) {
         yield
         return dt;
     }
 }

 // As an example
 TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(09, 0, 0);
 TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0);
 var range = Range(start.Ticks, end.Ticks);
```

**Result :**

```
09:00:00
10:00:00
11:00:00
12:00:00
```

What I would like to get is a time range ( increment by minutes instead of hours ):

**Expected result:**

```
09:00:00
09:01:00
09:02:00
09:03:00
  ...
11:59:00
12:00:00
```

What can I do to make this works?

Comment: So you have the code that increments by 1 hour, and now you want to change it to increment 1 minute. What is the problem here? Surely given the code you have you can make a stab at solving this.

Comment: I have already test the increment using minutes but it add one minute in every hour and not 60 minutes

Comment: _"I have already test the increment using minutes but it add one minute in every hour and not 60 minutes"_ -- there's no clear reason why changing `new TimeSpan(1,0,0)` in the code you posted to `new TimeSpan(0,1,0)` (the most obvious change that would match what you _claimed_ to have done) would not result in the correct output. But you didn't bother to provide _that_ code, i.e. the code you attempted but which doesn't work, so there's no way to usefully answer the question. Please read [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_TimeSpan__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_) for the `TimeSpan` constructor.

```
public TimeSpan (int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
```

Change the assignment in your for-loop to

```
dt = dt.Add(new TimeSpan(0,1,0))
```

since the second parameter refers to the minutes. The first one is the hours.
Or you can use

```
dt = dt.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
```

to make it more clear when reading the code later.